# How to fix GCC type warning on variable returned by the parser generator?

Tags: c, parsing, peg, packcc

I expect Packcc parser generator "$0s" or "$0e" variables to throw an int in the parser actions, because theses variables represents a position in the input.

I made a minimal parser that prints the position of the last char of the word.

```
word <- [a-z]+[\n]    {printf("Position %i\n", $0e);}

%%

int main()
{
    pcc_context_t *ctx = pcc_create(NULL);
    while(pcc_parse(ctx, NULL));
    pcc_destroy(ctx);
    return 0;
}
```

After parser generation using "packcc" command I compile the C generated file then Gcc sends this warning.

`warning: type defaults to 'int' in type name [-Wimplicit-int]`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: On which line is the warning?  You'll probably have to look at the parser output to see what's going on.

Comment: line 888:5 "#define _0e ((const)__pcc_in->data.leaf.capt0.range.end)
    printf("str %d\n", _0e); "

Comment: I get no such warning when I build your parser with the latest version of packcc from github, and for me the line in question has `const int` instead of `const`.  What version of packcc are you using?

Comment: Also for me that line has `printf("Position %i"...)`, matching the source code, instead of `"str %d"`.  Are you sure you are building the same file you posted here?  (You saved the file in your editor, etc?)

Comment: Sorry I messed the many tests i made. With the file posted here it is 888:5 "#define _0e ((const)__pcc_in->data.leaf.capt0.range.end)
    printf("Position %i\n", _0e);"

Comment: I use 1.3.0. I will try to build the master.

Comment: You're right. The master fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in that version of the packcc parser generator.  It is now [fixed](https://github.com/arithy/packcc/commit/109f531b735cdffed9dca50e0713160f89940239) in master, so try upgrading.

Or you can simply ignore the warning as the type should indeed be `int`.